# Xamarin retrieve bindableproperty through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, xamarin

I have the following 2 lines of code:

```
var setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = styleType.GetRuntimeProperty(propName) as BindableProperty;
```

But this is clearly wrong as PropertyInfo and BindableProperty are actually very unrelated in their inheritance. So... how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BindableProperty instances are typically stored in static fields of the class, so you would obtain a reference to it like this:

```
        var setter = new Setter();
        setter.Property = (BindableProperty)styleType.GetRuntimeField(propName).GetValue(null);
```

Where propName would be the name of the BindableProperty rather than the property (i.e. "CommmandProperty" instead of "Command" on Button).